# How to get variable from component for put on the App.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend

even by searching on the internet I did not find, or in all that I did not understand.
My problem: I would like the "inputVal" variable found in the "InputField.js" component to be found where there is "!!HERE!!" in the "App.js" component(on the fetch)
please help me
thank you for reading my message!

```
export default function InputField() {
  
  function handleSubmit(e) {
    // Prevent the browser from reloading the page
    e.preventDefault();

    // Read the form data
    const form = e.target;
    const inputVal = form.myInput.value;

    console.log(inputVal);
  }

  return (
    <form method="post" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input name="myInput" id="adress-field" placeholder="Enter adress" autoComplete="on" />
      <button type="submit" id="adress-button">Send</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

```
import './App.css';
import AccountNumber from "./components/AccountNumber";
import InputField from "./components/InputField";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

function App() {

  //token fetch
  const [tockens, setTockens] = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true)
    fetch("https://api.multiversx.com/accounts/!!HERE!!/tokens")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => setTockens(json))
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false)
      })
      console.log(tockens); 
  }, [])


  function round(nr, ten) { // arondi un chiffre.
    return Math.round(nr * ten) / ten;
}

function numberWithSpaces(nr) { // formate un chiffre(x xxx xxx).
    return nr.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");
}



  return (
    <content className="content">
        <div className="up-side">
            <div className="account-number-box">
                <p id="p-account-number">Total number of accounts</p>
                <p id="account-number"><AccountNumber/></p>
            </div>
            <div className="adress-search">
                {InputField()}
            </div>
            <p>{window.inputVal}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="down-side">
            <table className="Token-section-output">
            

              {loading ? (
                <div>Loading...</div>
              ) : (
                <>
                  <h1>Tockens</h1>
                  <table className='Token-section-output' border={0}>
                    <tr className='token-row-type'>
                      <th className='token-column'>Name</th>
                      <th className='center-column'>Price</th>
                      <th>Hold</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr className="space20"/>

                    
                    {tockens.map(tocken => (
                      <tr className='token-row' key={tocken.id}>
                        <td className='token-column'>
                        <img className="img-Tockens" src = {tocken?.assets?.pngUrl ?? "img/Question.png"} /> 
                          <p>{tocken.name}</p> 
                        </td>

                        <td className='center-column'> <p>${round(tocken.price, 10000000)}</p> </td>

                        <td> 
                          <p>{round(tocken.balance / Math.pow(10, tocken.decimals), 10000000)}</p> 
                          <p className='token-hold'>${round(tocken.valueUsd, 10000000)}</p>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    ))}

                  </table>
                </>
              )}


            </table>
        </div>   
    </content>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I not very good in react and i mak search on internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to extend your `InputField` component to accept a callback function, that can be passed by your app:

```
export default function InputField({onSubmit}) {
  
  function handleSubmit(e) {
    // Prevent the browser from reloading the page
    e.preventDefault();

    // Read the form data
    const form = e.target;
    const inputVal = form.myInput.value;

    console.log(inputVal);
    onSubmit(inputVal)
  }

  ...
}
```

And in your App you need to pass that callback to your component:

```
<div className="adress-search">
  <InputField onSubmit={handleSearchSubmit} />
</div>
```

Note: Components are not consumed by calling them like functions.

In your App logic, you'll need another state to hold your search value:

```
...
const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState(null);

const handleSearchSubmit = (val) => {
  setSearchValue(val);
}

useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true)
    fetch(`https://api.multiversx.com/accounts/${searchValue}/tokens`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => setTockens(json))
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false)
      });
    console.log(tockens); 
}, [searchValue])
...
```